# How to include sphinx 4 in a java swing application

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gson, cmusphinx

Can anyone tell me how i could include sphinx4 into my java swing project and also i am not able to find how to install gson and json.. I am using netbeans 7.1.2

Comment: You would include outside libraries in a Swing application the same as you would include them in a non-Swing application. Include their jar files in your classpath or your ide's build path. The NetBeans tutorials will show you how to do the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Wow, I used sphinx4 in my dissertation project 6 years ago!

I can't remember too much about it now unfortunately but you can download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/sphinx4/)

Extract the jar and add it to your classpath.  Once the jar is on the classpath you should be able to run the sample applications like [this](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/sphinx4/doc/ProgrammersGuide.html)

You don't need to install json - json is a language and you can use gson to parse it.
You can download the gson jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list) and add it to your classpath.